# jQuery delegated events work like direct events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I add dynamic button in my page and I want making an AJAX request when I'm clicking on it.

But my code handles every document's click, what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var $selButton=$("input[id^=btn_match_]"); 

  $(document).on("click", $selButton, function (e) {
      //  code is executing on every click on the page              
      //  and not only on button click
  });
</script>
```

One of my buttons:

```
<input id="btn_match_26179" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is supposed to be a string, not a jQuery object. If it is not a string, then it will get passed as `event.data` to the handler, instead of acting as a selector. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Try this:

```
  var selector = "input[id^=btn_match_]";

  $(document).on("click", selector, function (e) {
      // ...
  });
```